# jquery trigger multiple click event using for loop and random eq

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a click event on multiple random elements. I used this below code but not working. It just triggering one time only.

```
$('.dbl_rand_txt>li').on('click', function(e) { 
  var dbl_rand_no = $(this).children('span').children('a').text();
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  for (var i = 1; i <= dbl_rand_no; i++) {
     $(".tab-content li").eq(random).click();
  }
});
```

Comment: are you trying to trigger the click event if clicked on the `.dbl_rand_txt>li` ?

Comment: also do you have approx `100` `<li>` inside the `.tab-content`

Comment: Yes @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to run the following code snippet and observe the result.

```js
$('.dbl_rand_txt > li').on('click', function(e) {
  var dbl_rand_no = $(this).children('span').children('a').text();
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  for (var i = 1; i <= dbl_rand_no; i++) {
     $(".tab-content li").eq(random).click();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dbl_rand_txt">
  <li><span><a>10</a></span></li>
  <li><span><a>5</a></span></li>
  <li><span><a>2</a></span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="tab-content">
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 0');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 1');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 2');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 3');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 4');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 5');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 6');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 7');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 8');"></li>
  <li onclick="console.log('clicked 9');"></li>
</ul>
```

its just an example based on your question. see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to convert `string` returned via `dbl_rand_no` to `Number`

Since `random` is calculated once, `$(".tab-content li").eq(random)` will always return you same element. Move `random` calculation inside the `for` loop if you want to target different element.

```
$('.dbl_rand_txt>li').on('click', function (e) {

    //Convert string to number
    var dbl_rand_no = parseInt($(this).children('span').children('a').text(), 10);
    for (var i = 1; i <= dbl_rand_no; i++) {
        //Calculate random for different element
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

        $(".tab-content li").eq(random).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can ypu please upload it in js fiddle

Comment: @GummidiBhaskararao, Sure create one and I will update for you

Comment: @GummidiBhaskararao  have you tried $(selector).eq(random).trigger('click')?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var dbl_rand_no = Number($(this).children('span').children('a').text());
```

Also put your random function inside foor loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move you random number generation inside the loop so that as many time the loop has to go it should generate a new random number every time, and use `.trigger('click')` to trigger the function rather than `.click()` although it is the short hand for `trigger('click')` as calling `.click()` without the params will call the click event,  it will call one less function and `.trigger("click")` is faster see [Here](http://jsperf.com/trigger-vs-not-trigger)

See a demo below

```js
$('.dbl_rand_txt>li').on('click', function(e) {
  var dbl_rand_no = parseInt($(this).children('span').children('a').text());
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= dbl_rand_no; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    $(".tab-content li").eq(random).trigger('click');
  }
});

$(".tab-content li").on("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked <li> with text", $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dbl_rand_txt">
  <li><span><a href="#.">1</a></span></li>
  <li><span><a href="#.">2</a></span></li>
  <li><span><a href="#.">3</a></span></li>
  <li><span><a href="#.">4</a></span></li>
  <li><span><a href="#.">5</a></span></li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab-content">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```